# Slide the overlay to whole page in mobile browsers - using Javascript media queries

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries, flickity

I've been looking through the w3schools tutorial on using media queries with Javascript and I'm having trouble getting my overlay to slide the whole page on mobile browsers.

In desktop browsers, the overlay slides left 50% upon clicking the transformicon.

Using this example [Media queries using Javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_matchmedia)

Here's the new function I would like to add.

```
function myFunction(x) {
  if (x.matches) { // If media query matches
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.left = "100%";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.left = "50%";
  }
}


var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 400px)")
myFunction(x) // Call listener function at run time
x.addListener(myFunction) // Attach listener function on state changes
```

When I add the above function to the existing function listed in the snippet, The overlay is already visible and does not slide the whole way when the viewport is less than or equal to 400px.

I would also like the arrows in the slider to be hidden upon clicking the overlay. The class name for the arrows is

```
.flickity-prev-next-button
```

Here's a snippet of what it looks like without the new function for your reference.

```js
function openNav() {
  // if the element has the class tcon-transform (added/removed before calling this)
  if (event.target.classList.contains("tcon-transform")) {
    // the original icon was the plus: open the navigation
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.left = "50%";
  } else {
    // the original icon was the minus: close the navigation
    closeNav();
  }

  function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.left = "100%";
  }
}
```

```css
.flickity-page-dots {
  display: none;
}

.main-carousel {
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 0;
}

.carousel-cell img {
  max-width: 35%;
  /* full width */
  height: auto;
}

.carousel-cell {
  width: 100%;
  /* full width */
  background: #FFFFFF;
  /* center images in cells with flexbox */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/v0.7.19/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/zerodevx/zero-transformicon/v0.1.0/build/zero-transformicon.build.html">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="myNav" class="overlay"></div>
  <zero-transformicon icon="plus-minus" onclick="openNav()">

  </zero-transformicon>

  <div class="main-carousel" data-flickity='{ "cellAlign": "left","contain": true,"wrapAround":true }'>
    <div class="carousel-cell"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/G7WsYfK/RAVE-FW18-Drop-2-Lookbook-07-compressor.jpg"></div>
    <div class="carousel-cell"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/G7WsYfK/RAVE-FW18-Drop-2-Lookbook-07-compressor.jpg"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here's a snippet of what it looks like upon adding the new function. I've added 
the line `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`to the head tag as per your suggestion but the result is the same - Overlay slides only 50% of the page.

```js
function openNav() {
  // if the element has the class tcon-transform (added/removed before calling this)
  if (event.target.classList.contains("tcon-transform")) {
    // the original icon was the plus: open the navigation
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.left = "50%";
  } else {
    // the original icon was the minus: close the navigation
    closeNav();
  }

  function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.left = "100%";
  }
}

function myFunction(x) {
  if (x.matches) { // If media query matches
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.left = "100%";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.left = "50%";
  }
}


var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 400px)")
myFunction(x) // Call listener function at run time
x.addListener(myFunction) // Attach listener function on state changes
```

```css
.flickity-page-dots {
  display: none;
}

.main-carousel {
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 0;
}

.carousel-cell img {
  max-width: 35%;
  /* full width */
  height: auto;
}

.carousel-cell {
  width: 100%;
  /* full width */
  background: #FFFFFF;
  /* center images in cells with flexbox */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/v0.7.19/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/zerodevx/zero-transformicon/v0.1.0/build/zero-transformicon.build.html">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="myNav" class="overlay"></div>
  <zero-transformicon icon="plus-minus" onclick="openNav()">

  </zero-transformicon>

  <div class="main-carousel" data-flickity='{ "cellAlign": "left","contain": true,"wrapAround":true }'>
    <div class="carousel-cell"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/G7WsYfK/RAVE-FW18-Drop-2-Lookbook-07-compressor.jpg"></div>
    <div class="carousel-cell"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/G7WsYfK/RAVE-FW18-Drop-2-Lookbook-07-compressor.jpg"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please read [mcve] to learn how to post code in questions in a way so we can best answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Charlie. Will edit it now.

Comment: Are you able to get the media queries working in CSS. I am notice you do not have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` in your head tag.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this Paul. I've added the viewport tag to the snippet for your reference.